# Audio is not played on mobile chrome

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have an audio element with a mp3 src that is being played successfully on chrome desktop but when I try to play it on a mobile chrome browser it does not play.

```
 <audio id="my_sound">
    <source src="sounds/alarm.mp3">
 </audio>
```

The invoke code:

```
$("#my_sound").get(0).play();
```

The audio is played when a view is finished loading and not as a onclick event.

any idea what can I do?

Comment: You have to go through a user interaction.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

any idea on if / how can I do it without? it should be invoked once an event is being raised.

Comment: You ask them to click something so that you can play sound.  You cannot auto/play audio without a user interaction.  Read this: [Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).

Comment: You can't.  Chrome requires user interaction before it will play sound.  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes